# Why is this file not uploading?

Tags: php

PHP:

```
// If the user accessed the page by form submittal
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $filename = $_FILES["file-input"]["name"];
    $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $filesize = filesize($filename);
    $max_filesize = 524288;
// Array to hold errors
    $errors = array();

                if (!$filename) {
                    array_push($errors, "You didn't actually upload anything!");
            }
            else if ($extension != "txt") {
                    array_push($errors, "That's not a valid file-type. Please only use txt files.");
            }
            else if (filesize($filename)) {
                array_push($errors, "The txt file must not be empty. Give us a good story.");
            }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="upload-form">
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="upload">
<input type="file" name="file-input">
<span class="input-filename">Select a file...
    </span>
    <input type="button" value="Browse">
</div>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
                <span class="valid-formats">Valid input: .txt files &lt;= 512 KB</span>
            </form>
        </div>
```

I get the errors:

> Warning: filesize(): stat failed for todo.txt in
>   .../Dropbox/Projects/Website
>   Projects/serverside/assignment2/index.php on line 34
>
> Warning: filesize(): stat failed for todo.txt in
>   .../Dropbox/Projects/Website
>   Projects/serverside/assignment2/index.php on line 46
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(todo.txt): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in .../Dropbox/Projects/Website
>   Projects/serverside/assignment2/index.php on line 77

Comment: What of `No such file or directory in [...]` do you not understand? Read error messages!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file isn't in `$_FILES['file-input']['name']`. That will tell you that filename of the file on the client's computer when they uploaded. PHP stores the file in `$_FILES['file-input']['tmp_name']` on the server. Because of this, `pathinfo` won't work (it requires the file to be on disk).

You can split `$_FILES['file-input']['name']` on dots, and get the last value:

```
$parts = explode(".", $_FILES['file-input']['name']);
$extension = end($parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware to use this function on files/dirs which are NOT writeable: you will get a warning like:

Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for /var/www/xxx/yyy.php in /var/www/xxx/yyy.php on line 123

Answer (score 0):

The uploaded file path is stored in `$_FILES["file-input"]["tmp_name"];`, you need to use that if you want to perform operations on the file.

You're currently using `$_FILES["file-input"]["name"]` which is not what you want. That contains the original filename as it was on the user's machine.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this.

```
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file-input']['tmp_name'],"file_upload_location/".$_FILES['file-input']['name']);
```

It may work.